# VBScript Regular Expression to remove all chars but digits and hyphen ("-")

Tags: vbscript

can someone help me to write RegExp to remove all characters except numbers and hyphen (minus sign or "-") between them.

string looks like:
C:\Documents and Settings\User\Desktop\New Folder 2\New\Folder\1586-10 bougsfiugUYG(jygf) hoihd.xls

it needs to be:

1586-10

only.

the number of digits before -10 unspecified (can be 4-6); -10 itslef can be any two-digit number...

to make it easier. here is the function i found:

```
Public Function strClean (strtoclean)
Dim objRegExp, outputStr
Set objRegExp = New Regexp

objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
objRegExp.Global = True
objRegExp.Pattern = "((?![a-zA-Z0-9]).)+"
outputStr = objRegExp.Replace(strtoclean, "-")

objRegExp.Pattern = "\-+"
outputStr = objRegExp.Replace(outputStr, "-")

strClean = outputStr
End Function
```

the pattern currently makes this with file names:
C-Documents-and-Settings-Lena-Desktop-New-Folder-2-New-Folder-2-1588-11-sfiuhsgu-(fgRG75476)-skghgsiu.xls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`\d?\d?\d\d\d\d-\d\d`

`\d` is a digit

`?` means zero or one of the preceeding character

So `\d?` means that it can be 0 or 1 digit.

Edit: Added a sample of how to use it after the comments

```
Dim myRegExp
Set myRegExp = New RegExp
myRegExp.Pattern = "\d?\d?\d\d\d\d-\d\d"
Dim test
test = "C:\Documents and Settings\User\Desktop\New Folder 2\New\Folder\1586-10 bougsfiugUYG(jygf) hoihd.xls"
Set myMatches = myRegExp.Execute(Right(test, InStrRev(test, "\")))

WScript.Echo  myMatches(0)
```

Edit2: Code snippet used to call your code

```
Dim test
test = "C:\Documents and Settings\User\Desktop\New Folder 2\New\Folder\1586-10 bougsfiugUYG(jygf) hoihd.xls"
test = StrClean(test)

WScript.Echo  test
```

Comment: hi ho1,
sorry i didn't make it clear enough:

path C:\Documents and Settings\User\Desktop\New Folder 2\New\Folder\ - can be anything and any lenght - so all chars including \ before the last \ should be stripped, regardless whether they have number among them or not....

Comment: besides the logic of regexp should be to match everything apart from 1586-10 - so i can use it as a pattern to remove everything but 1586-10...

Comment: @user: I don't think I'd try to use a regex for that, I'd just use a `Right` and `InStrRev` as in my amended answer above. But I haven't used regex that much so there might be some neat solution using only a regex.

Comment: ok, don't matter if it's not regexp only, just need to achieve the target. still in your pattern you match DIGITS and HYPHEN only... and i need everything else BUT DIGITS and HYPHEN...

Comment: @user: Yep, but if you change the last line of the sample to being `test = myMatches(0)`, `test` will contain only the digits and hyphen and everything else has been removed.

Comment: oh yeeesss... but then i don't need such long regexp? will \d-\d\d sufficient?

Comment: Public Function strClean (strtoclean)
Dim objRegExp, myMatches
Set objRegExp = New Regexp

objRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
objRegExp.Global = True
objRegExp.Pattern = "\d?\d?\d\d\d\d-\d\d"

Set myMatches = objRegExp.Execute(Right(strtoclean, InStrRev(strtoclean, "\")))

strClean = myMatches(0)

End Function

Comment: @user: Not sure what's not working, I took the code from your previous comment and called it as can be seen in my *Edit2* and I got a message box saying `1586-10` which is correct as far as I understand your requirements?

Comment: i get "invalid procedure call or argument" on line 43, which is strClean = myMatches(0), code 800A0005

Comment: @user: Maybe your input doesn't have any matching bits? Try putting an `If myMatches.count > 0 Then` around that line and in the `Else` part set `strClean` to `""` or something.